# How does Pageant work when it has multiple keys loaded?

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, public-key, private-key

I'm trying to be organized with my work with servers and so with ssh keys but it seems to be impossible. So I'm thinking to move from Pageant to Serveauditor which is used by the CERN too. But before that I would like to understand what's wrong with the system.

So basically I manage 30-40 Linux host/guest and as I don't want contamination of any piracy stuff with one another, I'm using one different key/host or guest with a different passphrase of course.

So I wanted to use Pageant to work with all that (I'm connecting with Windows to those hosts/guests) but apparently I can't. So how Pageant does work? Is it offering all the keys at once to the server or iteratively and the server has to test every one of them? Is this some kind of basic protection of SSH server? Because if the good key isn't in the 5 first one apparently I have the error message *"Too many authentication failures"*. 
I don't think it's the `fail2ban` protection since I've stop it to test it.

Apparently also, If I'm using more than 5 DSA keys (which as I read it were more strong than RSA keys but it seems that PuTTY dev team don't agree with it) Pageant doesn't respond to PuTTY anymore, and it's the same than if I'm using more than 1 DSA key with several RSA keys.

So have I to conclude that pageant can't manage more than 5 or 6 hosts and if I need to do more, I need to assign each keys to the specific hosts in the PuTTY list or with another application like Serveauditor?

Best regards

Comment: PuTTY is fine with DSA, but OpenSSH (which is the server on Linux) 7.0 and up by default disables DSA (called DSS in SSH) see https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.0 PS: DSA is not stronger than RSA of the same size if both are properly implemented, and it is somewhat easier to mess up the implementation of DSA, which may be part of the reason the OpenSSH people decided as they did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PuTTY tries the keys retrieved from Pageant one by one, until it succeeds.

If you want PuTTY to try one specific key only, select it in the *Private key file for authentication*.

If the same key is already loaded in Pageant, PuTTY will retrieve it from Pageant (so it won't ask you for a passphrase).

Quoting [PuTTY documentation](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh-privkey):

> You can use the authentication agent Pageant so that you do not need to explicitly configure a key here; see [chapter 9](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter9.html). If a file is specified here with Pageant running, PuTTY will first try asking Pageant to authenticate with that key, and ignore any other keys Pageant may have. If that fails, PuTTY will ask for a passphrase as normal.

---

Also note that there's generally nothing wrong about using the same key for multiple servers.
See [What is the best practice: separate ssh-key per host and user VS one ssh-key for all hosts?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/40050/43677)

Comment: okey I understand better the system now, so there is definetely a limit of trials for a key then

Comment: Sure, see also [Too many authentication failures for \*username\*](http://superuser.com/q/187779/213663) + Note that there's generally nothing wrong about using the same key for multiple servers. See [What is the best practice: separate ssh-key per host and user VS one ssh-key for all hosts?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/40050/43677) (added to my answer).